Two golang goroutines sending messages to the same channel result in a 10-fold increase in time consumption?
Why is there such a significant difference in the time taken for sending and receiving data through a channel between two goroutines?
golang version 1.18
this is my code
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Message struct {
    msgID     int
    timeStamp int64
    timeTime  time.Time
    msgType   int
}

func main() {

    const buffer = 1000

    msgChan := make(chan *Message, buffer)
    timeSumType1 := time.Time{}
    timeSumType2 := time.Time{}

    go func() {

        for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            timeT1 := time.Now()
            msgChan <- &Message{msgID: i, msgType: 1}
            timeDiff := time.Now().Sub(timeT1)
            log.Println("type 1, id :", i, " <- timeDelta:", timeDiff)
            timeSumType1 = timeSumType1.Add(timeDiff)

        }

    }()

    go func() {

        for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            timeT1 := time.Now()
            msgChan <- &Message{msgID: i, msgType: 2}
            timeDiff := time.Now().Sub(timeT1)
            log.Println("type 2, id :", i, " <- timeDelta:", timeDiff)
            timeSumType2 = timeSumType2.Add(timeDiff)
        }

    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20)

    log.Println("type 1, timeSum:", timeSumType1)
    log.Println("type 2, timeSum:", timeSumType2)
}

the second goroutine sleep 100ms，the first goroutine sleep 1ms，
the first goroutine handle the msg type: 1
the second goroutine handle the msg type: 2
this is log ：
two goroutine  sending channel time cost log
two goroutine total cost time
I think the two goroutine should take almost same time with sending channel;
But Why does the second goroutine take several times longer for sending  operations compared to the first goroutine?
What internal factors cause this difference?

Please do not post pictures of text, include the information in the question body.

You are measuring total time spent sending 100 messages through a channel. The first goroutines takes at least 100msecs, probably overlapping with the second goroutine, so part of the second goroutine is probably running concurrently with the first goroutine, causing delays due to locking involved in channel send. Try this with second goroutine starting after >100ms delay.

And why use Go 1.18, which is no longer maintained? Use the most recent version, namely 1.23.

You are not measuring channel performance but how fast time.Time is. Stop doing microbenchmarks. Use benchmarking from package testing. Show code that reads the channel.

There's no meaningful answer we could give here without breaking down exactly how this is compiled and how it interacts with the runtime in a particular version and implementation of Go. The result is unrelated to the Go language. Intuitively it's not surprising, in general there are often fast-path optimizations when you have only a single case for contention.

I can provide a little help diagnosing that, although I don't know the reason. First, strip down the unnecessary parts and add tracing:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime/trace"
    "time"
)

type Message struct {
    msgID int
}

func fillChannel(ctx context.Context, sleep time.Duration, buffer int, regionType string) time.Duration {
    ch := make(chan Message, buffer)

    var timeSum time.Duration
    for i := 0; i < buffer; i++ {
        time.Sleep(sleep)
        timeT1 := time.Now()
        trace.WithRegion(ctx, regionType, func() {
            ch <- Message{msgID: i}
        })
        timeSum += time.Since(timeT1)
    }

    return timeSum
}

func main() {
    const buffer = 100

    t, err := os.Create("trace.out")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    err = trace.Start(t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    timeSumType1 := fillChannel(ctx, 1*time.Millisecond, buffer, "1ms")
    timeSumType2 := fillChannel(ctx, 100*time.Millisecond, buffer, "100ms")

    trace.Stop()
    t.Close()

    log.Println("type 1, timeSum:", timeSumType1)
    log.Println("type 2, timeSum:", timeSumType2)
}

go run this:
2024/08/14 14:31:06 type 1, timeSum: 180.83µs
2024/08/14 14:31:06 type 2, timeSum: 1.224414ms

then do go tool trace trace.out and click on “User-defined regions”:

